# Spark structured streaming error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming

I am trying to execute the following code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType(
StructField("id", LongType, false) ::
StructField("name", StringType, true) ::
StructField("city", StringType, true) :: Nil)


case class Person(id: Long, name: String, city: String)

import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders

val schema = Encoders.product[Person].schema


val people = spark.readStream.schema(schema).csv("/data/pncdw/scratch/test/*.csv").as[Person]

val population = people.groupBy('city).agg(count('city) as "population")

import scala.concurrent.duration._

import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.{OutputMode, Trigger}

val populationStream = population.
writeStream.
format("console").
trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(30.seconds)).
outputMode(OutputMode.Complete).
queryName("textStream").start
```

but I am getting this error:

```
ERROR : scala> populationStream.trigger(Trigger.once)
<console>:43: error: not found: value Trigger
populationStream.trigger(Trigger.once)
```

I have loaded all the jars and dependencies as it is shown below.

```
spark-shell --jars "/opt/projects/user/PLT8139/testjars/spark-xml_2.11-0.4.1.jar","/opt/projects/user/PLT8139/testjars/spark-avro_2.11.4.0.0.jar","/opt/projects/user/PLT8139/testjars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.1.jar","/opt/projects/user/PLT8139/testjars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11-
2.1.1.jar","/opt/projects/user/PLT8139/testjars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-10-assembly_2.11-2.1.1.jar","/opt/projects/user/PLT8139/testjars/spark-streaming_2.11-2.1.1.jar",,"/opt/projects/user/PLT8139/testjars/spark-sql_2.11-2.1.1.jar" --driver-memory 3g --executor-memory 3g --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 2
```

Comment: It is `Trigger.Once` not `Trigger.once`.

Comment: corrected. but still same error

Answer (score 0):

`trigger` is a property of the [`DataStreamWriter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter).

You are calling it on the `populationStream` which is `StreamingQuery` returned from by `start` method.

If you want to set in for the query, replace existing one:

```
val populationStream = population.
  writeStream.
  format("console").
  trigger(Trigger.Once).
  outputMode(OutputMode.Complete).
  queryName("textStream").start
```

Comment: @user9830431 sorry, din get it.

Comment: below is an example from apache library, doesnt work in my case though

Scala Example:

df.writeStream.trigger(ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))